# Chrome Extension Stats not updating

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chrome-web-store

For the last week or so, stats on my Chrome Extension have stopped being reported.

I recently released an update which corresponds with those dates but there was no code change that should have caused the stats change.

The only thing I can think that caused this is because the app was renamed with the update. Does anyone have any evidence of this causing issues?

[image: Stats graph for Google Chrome Analytics]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about the data collection and behind scenes processing of a third party service.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

this has been happening for years at the chrome store. sometimes it takes many days for stats to show, and some days are never updated. it usually happens on the same dates to most developers. mine is now also missing stats for several days.

if you link your extension with google analytics, you can then see installs from analytics but its not the same, as the chrome stats also substract uninstalls (not tracked in analytics).

To link the store with analytics, go to "Edit" in the chrome developer dashboard, scroll down to the "analytics" section and enter an analytics ID. Then you can use the analytics page to view your stats.
I couldnt find an official link but this one covers setting the ID:
http://www.asked.press/you-can-add-a-google-analytics-id-to-your-projects/2272765/

To view your install stats from analytics, do a Report on Behavior:Site content:content drilldown.
Use primary dimension "Page path level 1" to compare views (/webstore/) versus installs (/track_install/).

Drill-down on either to get more stats (for example views per country or language).

If you drill-down on track_install, your "Page path level 2" views will now be divided by:
/detail/search/related_tab/wall/ and others like "large marquee" (while you are an editors choice and shown in the front-page)
These tells you where the user saw and clicked to install your extension (Directly from a search, from the details page, from a marquee, etc).

More stuff can be done. If you set-up an analytics custom goal to count the times a url with prefix "/track_install/" is hit, you can more easily track installs from the mobile analytics app or set-up analytics custom alerts (for example if installs go over a certain number daily)

Comment: the whole portal is so buggy haha chrome doesn't seem to care much about the extension ecosystem

Comment: well, there is a beta dashboard that has some improvements. Lets hope that once its released it has better functionality.

Comment: this is unacceptable!!! we are in 2018 and stats takes 5 days to update????? what is going on google?

Comment: Is this issue the same for the current user count that is visible to the public? (Stats shows weekly user increment but not in the web store)

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately, this still happens. Zig, kudos for the answer! Now I can really see how my extension is performing. :)